# VideoJS in a Widget?

Tags: videos

I'm trying to get VideoJS plugin to work in a Widget. 
I tried to add a PHP widget and write, as it said in the manual:

```
[video mp4="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"]
```

But it just shows the code as is, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display shortcodes in widgets  , use a regular text widget, and add this line to your theme's functions.php file:

```
// Use shortcodes in text widgets.
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

This tells WordPress to render the shortcodes in widgets.

and if you want to call  your shortcode by php you can use [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function

```
// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).
do_shortcode('[video mp4="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4"]');
```

To get a better understanding of shortcodes check out [**this tutorial**](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/shotcodes-because-its-shorter) which covers: What shortcodes are, How to use shortcodes, ,How to define your own. and How to use them in widgets.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a WordPress shortcode in PHP code. You'll need to find the corresponding function and use that.